# How to get Cisco port information by SNMP in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, snmp

I am going to get Cisco switch port information such as vlan, mac address table etc.
Is it possible to get it via SNMP in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily consume net-snmp command line tools to achieve your goal, but if you want to utilize a cmdlet or native .NET API, by far I don't think you can.